# Integration of the product of pdf & cdf of normal distribution 

Tags: probability-distributions, integration

Denote the pdf of normal distribution as $\phi(x)$ and cdf as $\Phi(x)$. Does anyone know how to calculate $\int \phi(x) \Phi(\frac{x -b}{a}) dx$? Notice that when $a = 1$ and $b = 0$ the answer is $1/2\Phi(x)^2$. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Yes, a>0, but I am not clear about what you mean.. Can you explain that in details?

Comment: In fact I made a miscomputation. I used below a different approach. 

Comment: This question is available on mathoverflow.net at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127086/integral-of-the-product-of-normal-density-and-cdf/282500

Answer (score 14):

This might be a setting where relying on the *probabilistic meaning* of the functions $\phi$ and $\Phi$ saves ink and tedious computations.

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote standard normal random variables. Then $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty u(x)\phi(x)\mathrm dx=E(u(X))$ for every suitable function $u$  and $\Phi(x)=P(Y\leqslant x)$ for every real number $x$. 
Using this for the function $u:x\mapsto\Phi((x-b)/a)$ and assuming furthermore that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, one sees that the integral to be computed is
$$
(\ast)=E(\Phi((X-a)/b))=P(Y\leqslant(X-b)/a).
$$
Thus,
$$
(\ast)=P(Z\geqslant b),
$$
where $Z=X-aY$ (this step uses the fact that $a\gt0$). Now, the random variable $Z$ is normal as a linear combination of independent gaussian random variables, with mean $0$ and variance $1+a^2$, hence $Z=\sqrt{a^2+1}\cdot T$, where $T$ is standard normal. Thus,
$$
(\ast)=P(T\geqslant b/\sqrt{a^2+1})=1-\Phi\left(b/\sqrt{a^2+1}\right).
$$
Likewise, if $a\lt0$, then $(\ast)=\Phi\left(b/\sqrt{a^2+1}\right).$

In particular, if $b=0$ then, for every $a\ne0$, $(\ast)=\frac12$.

Comment: [As already explained](http://mathoverflow.net/a/127094/4661).

Comment: There seems to be a minor mistake. (*) =E(phi((x-b)/a)), not (*)=E(phi((x-a)/b)). Since it's just swaping a and b, I couldn't edit (must edit more than some number of words).

Answer (score 6):

We have $\phi(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{†^2}2\right)$ and $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\phi(t)dt$. We try to compute
$$ I(a,b):=\int\phi(x)\Phi\left(\frac{x-b}a\right)dx.$$
Using the dominated convergence theorem, we are allowed to take the derivative with respect to $b$ inside the integral. We have 
$$\partial_bI(a,b)=\int\phi(x)\left(-\frac 1a\right)\phi\left(\frac{x-b}a\right)dx$$
and 
\begin{align}
2\pi\phi(x)\phi\left(\frac{x-b}a\right)&=\exp\left(-\frac 12\left(x^2+\frac{x^2}{a^2}-2\frac{bx}{a^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)\right)\\\
&=\exp\left(-\frac 12\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}\left(x^2-2\frac b{a^2+1}x+\frac{b^2}{a^2+1}\right)\right)\\\
&=\exp\left(-\frac 12\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}\left(x-\frac b{a^2+1}\right)^2-\frac 12\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2+1}-\frac{b^2}{(a^2+1)^2}\right)\right)\\\
&=\exp\left(-\frac 12\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}\left(x-\frac b{a^2+1}\right)^2\right)\exp\left(-\frac{b^2}{2a^2}\frac{a^2+1-1}{a^2+1}\right)\\\
&=\exp\left(-\frac 12\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}\left(x-\frac b{a^2+1}\right)^2\right)\exp\left(-\frac{b^2}{2(a^2+1)}\right).
\end{align}
Integrating with respect to $x$, we get that 
$$\partial_b I(a,b)=-\frac 1{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\phi\left(\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right).$$
Since $\lim_{b\to +\infty}I(a,b)=0$, we have 
\begin{align}I(a,b)&=\int_b^{+\infty}\frac 1{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\phi\left(\frac s{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right)ds\\\
&=\int_{b/\sqrt{a^2+1}}^{+\infty}\phi(t)dt = 1 - \Phi(b/\sqrt{a^2+1}).
\end{align}
This can be expressed with the traditional erf function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but it seems that the "Integrating with respect to x" part is not correct. Can you double-check or add some more explanation on that part? Thank you!

Comment: The result of the integration step should contains some erf function of x instead of $\phi$ in the result, and the exp(-b^2/2/(a^2+1)) part should not be omitted.

Comment: I integrate on the whole real line with respect to $x$, and I do the substitution $\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}\left(x-\frac b{a^2+1}\right)^2=t^2$. I didn't omit the exponential term, since I wrote it using $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you but I still think that you miss something. I think the result is not correct as $\int_{b\sqrt{a^2+1}}^{+\infty}\phi(t)dt$ is a constant that does not depends on $x$ or $t$. Would you like to double check your result? Thank you very much!

Comment: The only fixed parameters are $a$ and $b$, we integrate with respect to $x$. Hence it's normal that $x$ doesn't appears in the final result. 

Comment: Well, when a = 1 and b = 0, the answer should be $1/2 \Phi(x)^2$ instead of $1/2$ in your result. The answer should depend on $x$. Would you like to double-check your answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: If the answer should depend on $x$, I don't understand the problem: it's like if you ask to compute $\int_0^a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$ and you say that the result should depend on $x$. Where do you integrate? 

Comment: It is an indefinite integral.

Comment: Now I see that your result is correct for definite integral, but I am really expecting a closed-form result for the indefinite integral and it does not seem to be doable. Anyway thank you very much for your help, Davide.

Comment: After the last integral, instead of saying "This can be expressed with the traditional erf function.", why not just say "$=1-\Phi\left(b\sqrt{a^2+1}\right)$"?

Comment: Quesiton: how are you managing to integrate `-exp(-x^2)`? Wouldnt this normally not be possible in closed form, except in the case of a definite integral, with bounds/limits?

Comment: Thinking this through, I guess the answer is: the answer given above assumes we are integrating from `-\infty` up to `\+infty`? which kind of makes sense. But I think it might be worth stating this explicitly perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

1. The last equation should be integral from $b/\sqrt{a^2+1}$
2. In `I(a, b)`, `a` is supposed to be positive. When $a<0$, the answer will be $\int_{-\infty}^{b/\sqrt{a^2+1}} \phi(t) dt$