# Integral of the product of Normal density and cdf

Tags: pr.probability

I am struggling with an integral pretty similar to one already resolved in MO (link: [Integration of the product of pdf & cdf of normal distribution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101469/integration-of-the-product-of-pdf-cdf-of-normal-distribution) ). I will reproduce the calculus bellow for the sake of clarity, but I want to stress the fact that my computatons are essentially a reproduction of the discussion of the previous thread.

In essence, I need to solve:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi\left(\frac{f-\mathbb{A}}{\mathbb{B}}\right)\phi(f)\,df,$$
where $\Phi$ is cdf of a standard normal, and $\phi$ its density. $\mathbb{B}$ is a negative constant.

As done in the aforementioned link, the idea here is to compute the derivative of the integral with respect to $\mathbb{A}$ (thanks to Dominated Convergence Theorem, integral and derivative can switch positions). With this, 
\begin{align*}
\partial_A\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi\left(\frac{f-A}{B}\right)\phi(f)\,df\right]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\partial_A\left[\Phi\left(\frac{f-A}{B}\right)\phi(f)\right]\,df=\int_{-\infty}^\infty-\frac{1}{B}\phi\left(\frac{f-A}{B}\right)\phi(f)\,df
\end{align*}
We note now that

$$\phi\left(\frac{f-A}{B}\right)\phi(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{(f-A)^2}{B^2}+f^2\right]\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2B^2}\left[f^2(1+B^2)+A^2-2Af\right]\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2B^2}\left[\left(f\sqrt{1+B^2}-\frac{A}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}\right)^2+\frac{B^2}{1+B^2}A^2\right]\right)$$

Finally, then,

$$\partial_A\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi\left(\frac{f-A}{B}\right)\phi(f)\,df\right]$$

$$\ \ \ \ \ =-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}B}\exp\left(-\frac{A^2}{2(1+B^2)}\right)\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2B^2}\left[f\sqrt{1+B^2}-\frac{A}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}\right]^2\right)\,df$$

and with the change of variable 
\begin{align}
\left[y\longmapsto f\frac{\sqrt{1+B^2}}{B}-\frac{A}{B\sqrt{1+B^2}}\Longrightarrow df=\frac{B}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}\,dy\right]
\end{align}
we get 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2B^2}\left[f\sqrt{1+B^2}-\frac{A}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}\right]^2\right)\,df=\frac{B}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(y)\,dy=\frac{B}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}
\end{align}
This means that 
\begin{align}
\partial_A\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi\left(\frac{f-A}{B}\right)\phi(f)\,df\right]&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}B}\exp\left(-\frac{A^2}{2(1+B^2)}\right)\frac{B}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}\phi\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}\right)
\end{align}
At this point, given that (as $\mathbb{B}$ is negative)
$$\Phi\left(\frac{f-A}{\mathbb{B}}\right)\phi(f)=0$$
when $\mathbb{A}\rightarrow-\infty$, the integral we are looking for is equal to
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\mathbb{A}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\mathbb{B}^2}}\phi\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{1+\mathbb{B}^2}}\right)\,dA
\end{align}
Again with the obvious change of variables
$$\left[y\longmapsto\frac{A}{\sqrt{1+\mathbb{B}^2}}\Longrightarrow\sqrt{1+\mathbb{B}^2}\,dy=dA\right]$$
one gets
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\mathbb{A}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\mathbb{B}^2}}\phi\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{1+\mathbb{B}^2}}\right)\,dA=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\mathbb{B}^2}}\sqrt{1+\mathbb{B}^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\mathbb{A}/\sqrt{1+\mathbb{B}^2}}\phi(y)\,dy=-\Phi({\mathbb{A}/\sqrt{1+\mathbb{B}^2}}).
\end{align}
The problem here is that this number should obviously be positive, so at some point I am missing a signal. As the computations seem sound to me, I would like to see if anyone could help me to find my mistake.

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: A faulty step is "At this point, given that" since when $B\to-\infty$, the product you consider goes to $\Phi(0)\phi(f)=\frac12\phi(f)\ne0$.

Comment: Oh god that's more than faulty, thats outrageous ;). Many thanks for your help!

Comment:  At the end this is not as outrageous as it seemed XD: in fact it is a typo, it should read "when A\rightarrow-\infty". Then the subsequent line holds. I have edited it.

Comment: Even though the original question is satisfactory solved, I am still curious with the mistake in the computations above, so any help would be appreciated ;).

Comment: minor typo-ette in the third line: missing the $1/2\pi$

Comment: $\mathbb{B}$ is a negative constnat. Therefore when you substitute the variable $f$ into $y$, I think you need to swap the bounds over?

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice list:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions

Comment: (Note that there's also a stray $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in line 7

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Nice! But missing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(\Phi(x)) \phi(x)\,dx$, which is what I need. So, I will need to learn to calculate it myself :)

Comment: This looks interesting:  https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Distributions-Involving-Gaussian-Variables/dp/0387346570/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1506937297&sr=1-1&keywords=Probability+Distributions+Involving+Gaussian+Random+Variables%3A+A+Handbook+...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Not available in Kindle... I guess reading mathoverflow and wikipedia is not a terrible method, and doesnt involve killing trees :)

Comment: That point about killing trees is overdone---the real p0roblem with comercial nordic forrests is that the market is disappearing, so the trees cannot be cut, so tree diseases spread like never before, this at least is the real ecological problem with scandinavian forrests, I guess with US and canadian too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The horror, the horror](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNUr__-VZeQ)... :-)

Recall that $\Phi(x)=P[X\leqslant x]$ for every $x$, where the random variable $X$ is standard normal, and that, for every suitable function $u$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u(x)\phi(x)\mathrm dx=E[u(Y)],
$$
where the random variable $Y$ is standard normal. Using this for $u=\Phi$, one sees that the integral $I$ you are interested in is
$$
I=P[X\leqslant B^{-1}(Y-A))]=P[BX\geqslant Y-A]=P[Z\leqslant A],
$$
where $Z=Y-BX$, where $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. standard normal, and where we used the fact that $B\lt0$ to reverse the inequality sign. Now, the random variable $Z$ is centered gaussian with variance $\sigma^2=1+B^2$, hence $Z=\sigma U$ with $U$ standard normal, and
$$
I=P[U\leqslant A/\sigma]=\Phi(A/\sqrt{1+B^2}).
$$

Comment: This completely solves the original problem. Thanks! 

Comment: +1 for the great answer! There seems a gap for me at $I=P[X\leqslant B^{-1}(Y-A))]$. Could you explain it a little bit?

Comment: @Randel How can you think this is a great answer if you feel there is a gap at the first step, I wonder... Anyway, thanks for the appreciation, and note that $$\int_\mathbb R\Phi(B^{-1}(x-A))\varphi(x)\mathrm dx=E(\Phi(B^{-1}(Y-A)))$$ and that, for every $x$, $$\Phi(x)=P(X\leqslant x),$$ hence, using the independence of $X$ and $Y$, one gets the formula in the post.

Comment: I am curious: What is the significance of taking the product of the PDF and CDF? Then, I believe the integral take all possible values?

Answer (score 1):

When you do the change of variable, you are doing:

\begin{align}
\left[y\longmapsto f\frac{\sqrt{1+B^2}}{B}-\frac{A}{B\sqrt{1+B^2}}\Longrightarrow df=\frac{B}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}\,dy\right]
\end{align}

.. which is correct. However, we need to apply the same change of variable to the bounds, ie to $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. Given that $\mathbb{B}$ is a negative constant, the bounds will change sign, becoming $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. So we will have:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2B^2}\left[f\sqrt{1+B^2}-\frac{A}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}\right]^2\right)\,df=\frac{B}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\phi(y)\,dy=-\frac{B}{\sqrt{1+B^2}}
\end{align}

This sign change will then propagate through to the final answer, reversing its sign too.

Full working, based off your working above, but with some buggettes removed:

Start with:

$$
I = 
\def\A{\mathbb{A}}
\def\B{\mathbb{B}}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi\left(
   \frac{f - \A}
       {\B}
   \right)\phi(f)\, df
$$

Take derivative wrt $\A$:

$$
\partial_\A I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty
\partial_\A \left(
    \Phi \left(
        \frac{f - \A}{\B}
    \right)
    \phi(f)
\right)
\, df
$$

$$
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\left(
   \frac{-1}{\B}
\right)
\phi\left(
   \frac{f - \A}{\B}
\right)
\phi(f)
\,
df
$$

Looking at $E_1 = \phi\left(\frac{f - \A}{\B}\right) \phi(f)$:

$$
E_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi}
\exp \left(
    - \frac{1}{2}
    \left(
        \frac{f^2 - 2f\A + \A^2 + \B^2f^2}
           {B^2}
    \right)
\right)
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{2\pi} \exp\left( - \frac{1}{2\B^2}
   \left(
   \left(
   \sqrt{(1 + \B^2)}f - \A\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
   \right)^2
   - \frac{\A^2}
      {1 + \B^2}
    + \A^2
\right)
\right)
$$

$$
- \frac{\A^2}{1+\B^2} + \A^2
$$

$$
= \frac{-\A^2 + \A^2 + \A^2\B^2}
  {1 + \B^2}
  $$

$$
= \frac{\A^2\B^2}
   {1 + \B^2}
$$

Therefore $E_1$ is:

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}
\exp \left(
   -\frac{1}{2\B^2}
   \frac{\A^2\B^2}{1 + \B^2}
\right)
\exp \left(
    - \frac{1}{2\B^2} \left(
       f\sqrt{1 + \B^2} - \frac{\A}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
    \right)^2
\right)
$$

$$
=
\frac{1}{2\pi}
\exp \left(
   -\frac{\A^2}{2(1 + \B^2)}
\right)
\exp \left(
    - \frac{1}{2\B^2} \left(
       f\sqrt{1 + \B^2} - \frac{\A}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
    \right)^2
\right)
$$

Make change of variable:

$$
y = f\frac{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}{\B} - \frac{A}{\B\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
$$

Therefore:

$$
dy = \frac{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}{\B}\,df
$$

For the limits, we have $f_1 = -\infty$, and $f_2 = \infty$

$\sqrt{1 + \B^2}$ is always positive. $\B$ is always negative. Therefore:

$$
y_1 = +\infty, y_2 = -\infty
$$

Therefore:

$$
\partial_\A I =
\frac{-1}{\B}\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}
\exp \left(
  - \frac{\A^2} {2(1+\B^2)}
\right)
\exp \left(
  - \frac{1}{2} y^2
\right)
\frac{\B}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
\, 
dy
$$

$$
= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\frac{1}{\B}
\frac{\B}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
\exp \left(
  - \frac{\A^2}{2(1 + \B^2)}
\right)
\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\exp\left(
  -\frac{1}{2} y^2
\right)
\,
dy
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\B^2}}
\exp \left(
   - \frac{\A^2}{2(1 + \B^2)}
\right)
(1)
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
\phi\left(
   \frac{\A}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
\right)
$$

Now we need to re-integrate back up again, since we currently have $\partial_\A I$, and we need $I$.

Since we dont have limits, we'll need to find at least one known point.

We have the following integral:

$$
I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}} \int \phi\left(
    \frac{\A}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
\right)
\,d\A
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
\sqrt{1 + \B^2}
\Phi\left(
   \frac{\A}
      {\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
\right)
+ C
$$
... where $C$ is a constant of integration

$$
= \Phi \left(
   \frac{\A}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
\right)
+ C
$$

Looking at the original integral, we had/have:

$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi\left(
   \frac{f - \A}{\B}
\right)
\phi(f)
\,
df
$$

We can see that, given that $\B$ is negative, as $\A \rightarrow \infty$, $\Phi\left(\frac{f-\A}{\B}\right) \rightarrow \Phi(\infty) = 1$.

Therefore, as $\A \rightarrow \infty$, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(\cdot)\phi(f)\,df \rightarrow 1$

Meanwhile, looking at the later expression for $I$, ie:

$$
I= \Phi\left(
   \frac{\A}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
\right) + C
$$

... as $\A \rightarrow +\infty$, $\Phi\left( \frac{\A}{\sqrt{1 + \B^2}} \right) \rightarrow 1$

But we know that as $\A \rightarrow +\infty$, $I \rightarrow 1$.

Therefore, $C = 0$

Therefore:

$$
I = \Phi \left(
   \frac{\A}
      {\sqrt{1 + \B^2}}
\right)
$$