# Integral of the product of a gaussian pdf and cdf

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, integration, gaussian

I am trying to solve the integral of a gaussian cumulative distribution function and a gaussian probability function. On this site I have seen solutions of similar, less general integrals (e.g. [Integral of the product of Normal density and cdf](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127086/integral-of-the-product-of-normal-density-and-cdf)) . Does a closed form solution for this specific case exist?
$$\int_{s_2=-\infty }^{s_2=y}
\phi(s;\mu;\sigma)\times \Phi(r;
     cs_2;\tau)
 \text{d}{s} $$
where Φ is the cdf of a gaussian distribution, and ϕ its density.

Comment: That is too many subscripts for a question here. If you can write this as $$\int \phi(s;\mu,\sigma)\Phi(r;cs,\tau)ds$$ please edit the question like that!

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer on this page?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica cannot take such integrals, even for zero-mean normal distributions. So, it is highly unlikely that they can expressed in closed form.

Here is the image of the corresponding Mathematica notebook:

[image]

An exceptional trivial case is when the two normal distributions are the same:

[image]

That is, here we get $F(y)^2/2=\Phi(y)^2/2$, by the substitution $t=\Phi(x)$.