# Integral with linear function, Normal PDF, Normal CDF

Tags: pr.probability, integration, gaussian

I am trying to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_a^\infty x \Phi(cx+d) \phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) dx,$$
where $\Phi$, $\phi$ denote the CDF and PDF of the standard Normal $N(0,1)$.

I found this table of integrals but it includes only the indefinite integral:
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/03610918008812164?casa_token=0E6SYYGFkkUAAAAA:cd6Lp-PTXsVRR20JaMQcNV8twies8FQAV0sO0DgOcAMD-L8aKBjxwpbqjClYlcFdIIxNUTCrnySg

Can you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: You can try just doing an integration by parts to remove the x. The indefinite integral is more manageable because when you do integration by parts, the boundary term disappears. Are you looking for any particular bound?

Comment: Thanks! How do we find integrals of the form $\int_a^\infty x \phi(cx+d) \phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}) dx$ though? Is there a closed form solution?

Comment: @Margot. --- the integral in your comment, product of two $\phi$'s, has a closed form in terms of error functions ("complete the square"); but the integral in your question has the product of $\phi$ and $\Phi$, so that does not help.

Comment: After integrating by parts, I think this is what we find, right? Do you have a link for the internal in my comment? Thanks!

Comment: This is close but I don't know whether this can help <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498851/what-is-int-c-infty-phiabx-phi-x-dx-for-c-in-mathbbr/498875#498875>

Comment: I think you can derive the answer from <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions>

Answer (score 2):

the definite integral has a closed-form expression for $\mu=0$,

\begin{align}
& \int_a^\infty x \Phi(cx+d) \phi\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right) dx \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{c \sigma^3 e^{-\frac{d^2}{2 c^2 \sigma^2+2}}}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{c^2 \sigma^2+1}}\left[1-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{c \sigma^2 (c a+d)+a}{\sigma \sqrt{2 c^2 \sigma^2+2}}\right)\right] \\[8pt]
& -\sigma^2(2 \sqrt{2 \pi })^{-1}e^{-\frac{a^2}{2 \sigma^2}} \left[\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{c a+d}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-2\right]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks ! I know the expression from the table I shared. I am interested in the definite integral version, though.

Comment: Thanks! Can you show the steps?

Comment: as indicated in the comment above, integrate by parts to remove the $x$, then follow  the  steps of https://mathoverflow.net/a/101753/11260

Comment: Why does $\mu \neq 0$ cause issues?

Comment: the integral $\int \phi(x-\mu)\Phi(x)\,dx$ does not have a closed-form expression when $\mu\neq 0$

Comment: I found this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130958/computing-an-integral-involving-standard-normal-pdf-and-cdf Why can't we apply the result in the link using a linear transformation $y = x-\mu$?

Comment: I meant change of variables^

Comment: @Margot Yes you can do a COV, see the link in my comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The indefinite integral $\int x \Phi(\alpha x + \beta) \phi\left(x\right) \mathrm{d}x$ is given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions). Let's denote it by $I(\alpha,\beta,x)$.

The change of variables $y=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ in $\int_a^\infty x \Phi(cx+d) \phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \mathrm{d}x$ gives
$$\sigma\int_{\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}}^\infty (\mu + \sigma y) \Phi(c\sigma y +c\mu + d) \phi(y) \mathrm{d}y \\ = \sigma\mu\int_{\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}}^\infty\Phi(c\sigma y +c\mu + d)\phi(y)\mathrm{d}y +  \sigma^2\int_{\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}}^\infty y\Phi(c\sigma y +c\mu + d)\phi(y)\mathrm{d}y.$$

The second integral is ${\bigl[I(c\sigma,c\mu+d,x)\bigr]}_{\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}}^\infty$. The first integral can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/498875/8402).

---

## Edit

I checked with R and it is correct.

```
I <- function(a, b, x) {
  t <- sqrt(1+b^2)
  b/t * dnorm(a/t) * pnorm(x*t + a*b/t) - dnorm(x) * pnorm(a + b*x)
}
J <- function(a, b, w) {
  t <- sqrt(1+b^2)
  rho <- -b/t
  library(mvtnorm)
  pmvnorm(upper = c(a/t, w), sigma = cbind(c(1, rho), c(rho, 1)))
}
K <- function(a, b, w) {
  J(a, b, Inf) - J(a, b, w)
}

a <- 1
mu <- 1; sigma <- 1; c <- 2; d <- -1

mu*sigma * K(c*mu+d, c*sigma, (a-mu)/sigma) + 
  sigma^2*(I(c*mu+d, c*sigma, Inf) - I(c*mu+d, c*sigma, (a-mu)/sigma))
# 0.8796307

f <- function(x) { 
 x * pnorm(c*x+d) * dnorm((x-mu)/sigma)  
}
integrate(f, lower = a, upper = Inf)
# 0.8796307 with absolute error < 1.7e-08
```

---

## Edit

So if I didn't do a mistake, the final result is
$$
\sigma \left(\mu\Phi\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{t}\bigr) 
  - B_{\frac{-\beta}{t}}\Bigl(\frac{\alpha}{t}, v\Bigr)  
  + \sigma \Bigl(\frac{\beta}{t} \phi\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{t} \bigr) 
      \Bigl(1 - \Phi\bigl(tv+\frac{\alpha\beta}{t}\bigr)\Bigr) - 
      \phi(v)\Phi(\alpha + \beta v)\Bigr)\right)
$$
where $t = \sqrt{1+c^2\sigma^2}$, $\alpha = c\mu+d$, $\beta = c\sigma$, $v = \frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$, and $B_\rho$ is the [bivariate normal function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498851/what-is-int-c-infty-phiabx-phi-x-dx-for-c-in-mathbbr/498875#498875).

To be checked...